# laravel 8: how to use seeder in unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

im trying to get the data after seeding a simple json to database. Here's the code:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Database\Seeders\TagsSeeder;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class TagTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_GetTags()
    {
        $this->seed(TagsSeeder::class);
        $response = $this->get('/api/tags')->seeJson(["name" => "mytags"]);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

coding above based on documentation here: [database testing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#running-seeders)
but when i run the test with command

```bash
php artisan test ./tests/Unit/TagTest.php
```

it's return error below:

```
Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\TagTest::seed()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class :

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

Instead of this :

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

and extend TagTest from it.

currently you're extending from PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase and thats the reason why seeders not available because its PHPUnit test class not Laravel test class